# A portrait photo (JPG) is turned sideway after imagemagick converts it to a png file. How to stop this change of orientation?

Tags: imagemagick, png, jpeg, exif, imagemagick-convert

The original photo looks like this:

[image]

I convert the it to `png` using this command:

```
convert -strip -quiet -limit memory 2072580096 -quality 100 -alpha off -density 165% -scene 1 -colorspace sRGB tmpALcgg3.jpeg output.png
```

After conversion, it beccomes this:

[image]

When I inspect the file in Pixelmator, it is shown as '1'

[image]

which does not actually make much sense to me.

Then I used `exiftool` to extract the following information from the original file

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : 5844997216141312-442620002-3d31fc32-9012-489e-88d2-177bf0bd679f (1).jpeg
Directory                       : /Users/antkong/Downloads
File Size                       : 3.2 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:03:27 11:19:53+11:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:03:27 11:52:56+11:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:03:27 11:20:00+11:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : NIKON CORPORATION
Camera Model Name               : NIKON D90
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
X Resolution                    : 300
Y Resolution                    : 300
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : Ver.1.00
Modify Date                     : 2018:03:12 22:23:48
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Co-sited
Exposure Time                   : 1/30
F Number                        : 4.5
Exposure Program                : Not Defined
ISO                             : 800
Exif Version                    : 0221
Date/Time Original              : 2018:03:12 22:23:48
Create Date                     : 2018:03:12 22:23:48
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 2
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 4.6
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Light Source                    : Unknown
Flash                           : Auto, Did not fire
Focal Length                    : 40.0 mm
Maker Note Version              : 2.10
Quality                         : Normal
White Balance                   : Auto
Focus Mode                      : Manual
Flash Setting                   : Normal
Flash Type                      : 
White Balance Fine Tune         : 0 0
WB RB Levels                    : 1.26953125 1.9453125 1 1
Program Shift                   : 0
Exposure Difference             : 0
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Preview Image Start             : 10204
Preview Image Length            : 24280
Flash Exposure Compensation     : 0
ISO Setting                     : 800
Image Boundary                  : 0 0 4288 2848
External Flash Exposure Comp    : 0
Flash Exposure Bracket Value    : 0.0
Exposure Bracket Value          : 0
Crop Hi Speed                   : Off (4352x2868 cropped to 4352x2868 at pixel 0,0)
Exposure Tuning                 : 0
Serial Number                   : 6726314
VR Info Version                 : 0100
Vibration Reduction             : On
VR Mode                         : Normal
Active D-Lighting               : Auto
Picture Control Version         : 0100
Picture Control Name            : Standard
Picture Control Base            : Standard
Picture Control Adjust          : Default Settings
Picture Control Quick Adjust    : n/a
Brightness                      : Normal
Hue Adjustment                  : None
Filter Effect                   : n/a
Toning Effect                   : n/a
Toning Saturation               : n/a
Time Zone                       : +01:00
Daylight Savings                : No
Date Display Format             : D/M/Y
ISO Expansion                   : Off
ISO Expansion 2                 : Off
Lens Type                       : G VR
Lens                            : 18-105mm f/3.5-5.6
Flash Mode                      : Did Not Fire
Shooting Mode                   : Single-Frame, Auto ISO
Shot Info Version               : 0213
Firmware Version                : 1.00i
ISO2                            : 800
Light Switch                    : LCD Backlight
AF Area Mode Setting            : Auto-area
Center Focus Point              : Wide Zone
AF Assist                       : On
AF Point Illumination           : Auto
Focus Point Wrap                : No Wrap
AE Lock For MB-D80              : AE/AF Lock
MB-D80 Battery Type             : LR6 (AA alkaline)
Beep                            : On
Grid Display                    : On
ISO Display                     : Show ISO Sensitivity
Viewfinder Warning              : On
No Memory Card                  : Release Locked
Screen Tips                     : On
File Number Sequence            : Off
Shooting Info Display           : Auto
LCD Illumination                : Off
Easy Exposure Comp              : Off
Reverse Indicators              : + 0 -
Exposure Control Step Size      : 1/3 EV
Center Weighted Area Size       : 8 mm
Fine Tune Opt Matrix Metering   : 0
Fine Tune Opt Center Weighted   : 0
Fine Tune Opt Spot Metering     : 0
CL Mode Shooting Speed          : 3 fps
Exposure Delay Mode             : Off
Auto Bracket Set                : AE & Flash
Auto Bracket Order              : 0,-,+
Func Button                     : FV Lock
OK Button                       : Select Center Focus Point
AE Lock Button                  : AE/AF Lock
Command Dials Reverse Rotation  : No
Shutter Release Button AE-L     : Off
Metering Time                   : 6 s
Remote On Duration              : 1 min
Self Timer Time                 : 10 s
Self Timer Shot Count           : 1
Playback Monitor Off Time       : 10 s
Image Review Time               : 4 s
Menu Monitor Off Time           : 20 s
Shooting Info Monitor Off Time  : 10 s
Flash Shutter Speed             : 1/60 s
Internal Flash                  : TTL
Manual Flash Output             : Full
Repeating Flash Output          : 1/32
Repeating Flash Count           : 10
Repeating Flash Rate            : 10 Hz
Flash Warning                   : On
Commander Internal TTL Comp     : 0
Modeling Flash                  : Off
Auto FP                         : Off
Commander Group A TTL Comp      : 0
Commander Group B TTL Comp      : 0
Live View AF                    : Wide Area
Noise Reduction                 : Off
WB GRBG Levels                  : 256 325 498 256
Lens Data Version               : 0204
Exit Pupil Position             : 102.4 mm
AF Aperture                     : 4.6
Focus Position                  : 0x32
Focus Distance                  : 2.11 m
Lens ID Number                  : 158
Lens F Stops                    : 5.33
Min Focal Length                : 18.3 mm
Max Focal Length                : 106.8 mm
Max Aperture At Min Focal       : 3.6
Max Aperture At Max Focal       : 5.7
MCU Version                     : 160
Effective Max Aperture          : 4.6
Retouch History                 : None
Image Data Size                 : 3298230
Shutter Count                   : 40069
Flash Info Version              : 0103
Flash Source                    : None
External Flash Firmware         : n/a
External Flash Flags            : (none)
Flash Commander Mode            : Off
Flash Control Mode              : Off
Flash Compensation              : 0
Flash GN Distance               : 0
Flash Color Filter              : None
Flash Group A Control Mode      : Off
Flash Group B Control Mode      : Off
Flash Group C Control Mode      : Off
Flash Group A Compensation      : 0
Flash Group B Compensation      : 0
Flash Group C Compensation      : 0
Vari Program                    : Auto
Multi Exposure Version          : 0100
Multi Exposure Mode             : Off
Multi Exposure Shots            : 0
Multi Exposure Auto Gain        : Off
High ISO Noise Reduction        : Normal
Power Up Time                   : 2018:03:12 22:05:11
AF Info 2 Version               : 0100
Contrast Detect AF              : Off
AF Area Mode                    : Single Area
Phase Detect AF                 : Off
Primary AF Point                : (none)
AF Points Used                  : (none)
Contrast Detect AF In Focus     : No
File Info Version               : 0100
Memory Card Number              : 0
Directory Number                : 100
File Number                     : 0153
Retouch Info Version            : 0100
User Comment                    : 
Sub Sec Time                    : 00
Sub Sec Time Original           : 00
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 00
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 4288
Exif Image Height               : 2848
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version        : 0100
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
File Source                     : Digital Camera
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
CFA Pattern                     : [Green,Blue][Red,Green]
Custom Rendered                 : Normal
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
Digital Zoom Ratio              : 1
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 60 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Gain Control                    : Low gain up
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Normal
Subject Distance Range          : Unknown
GPS Version ID                  : 2.2.0.0
Thumbnail Offset                : 34644
Thumbnail Length                : 9197
Image Width                     : 4288
Image Height                    : 2848
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)
Aperture                        : 4.5
Auto Focus                      : Off
Blue Balance                    : 1.945313
Image Size                      : 4288x2848
Lens ID                         : AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 18-105mm f/3.5-5.6G ED
Lens Spec                       : 18-105mm f/3.5-5.6 G VR
Megapixels                      : 12.2
Preview Image                   : (Binary data 24280 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Red Balance                     : 1.269531
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 1.5
Shutter Speed                   : 1/30
Create Date                     : 2018:03:12 22:23:48.00
Date/Time Original              : 2018:03:12 22:23:48.00
Modify Date                     : 2018:03:12 22:23:48.00
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 9197 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.020 mm
Depth Of Field                  : 0.50 m (1.89 - 2.39 m)
Field Of View                   : 32.8 deg (1.24 m)
Focal Length                    : 40.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 60.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 17.75 m
Light Value                     : 6.2
```

The orientation, as you can see above, is set to 'Rotate 270 CW', but it does not really explain the outcome.

I want to keep the orientation unchanged because when I inspect it in browsers or app such as pixelmator, the original photo's orientation is upright.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your EXIF data shows:

Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW

So add -auto-orient to your command line:

```
convert -strip -quiet -limit memory 2072580096 -auto-orient tmpALcgg3.jpeg -quality 100 -alpha off -density 165% -scene 1 -colorspace sRGB  output.png
```

Comment: I see. May I ask why the outcome looks to me like 'rotate clockwise 90 degree'?

Comment: You need to rotate it 270 cw to get back to the correct view.

Comment: I see. So the orientation is not a description. It is more like an imperative. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, the text says "rotate" not "rotated". So that tells me the angle is what is need to be rotated to get it back to proper order. Other tools may tell you how much it has been rotated.